# Angular $routeParams - mix a parameter and text?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'd like to have a routes such as this:

```
/products/1-bananas
/products/2-apples
/products/3-oranges
...
/products/25-television
/products/26-router
```

Is it possible to mix a parameter ID with a text together? I would use this in a way where I would grab the productID on the pageload, and query a database for the relevant information.

I know a way to do this (that works) would be something like this:

```
/products/1/bananas
```

which could be designed as a Route like so:

```
/products/:productId/:productName
```

But I feel like the first way, where the ID and name is together in the same string, and separated by a dash, looks much cleaner.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: does that products/:productId-:productName work?

Comment: Oh wow, yes it does. Smacking my head right now at missing the obvious. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would caution you to avoid inventing new patterns and using them over existing ones. While you may feel that a hyphen is more readable, angular routes are based on RESTful design principles. The established pattern, resource/id/relation, is more scalable and understandable. You can imagine how quickly your scenario could get out of hand when you starting introducing additional types of apples or TVs, or even different manufacturers and farmers.

If you insist on your specified approach, you can set up your routes and resources like this:

```
 .when('/products/:id-:name', {
     templateUrl: '/assets/angular/templates/products.html',
      controller: 'ProductCtrl'
 })
```

And

```
.factory('Product', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/products/:id-:name', {});
    }
])
```

The hyphen is just a character, it has no special meaning so you can just use it. With this you should be able to get at the route params the way you wish.